# Configure Tensorflow In Linux VM under Windows 10

Tags: linux, tensorflow, bazel

I am using Ubuntu by virtualbox in Windows 10.

I have downloaded tensorflow using the command line function as stated in the official [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip)

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Then I went to tensorflow file and configure tensorflow by:

```
./configure
```

Then I answered a set of questions:

```
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python]: /usr/bin/python
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: -march=native
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n] n
jemalloc disabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] n
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
```

Here is the error I got:

```
     Configuration finished
     INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --expunge_async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
     ........................
     ERROR: /home/alexluk/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl:220:6:
 name 'WITH_GCP_SUPPORT' is not defined.
     ERROR: package contains errors: tensorflow/c.
     ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/c': Extension 'tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl' has errors.
```

Any idea on how to deal with that? Thanks.

---

Maybe it's related. When I run the following code:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

I got this error:

```
WARNING: Bazel Android NDK crosstools are based on Android NDK revision 12. The revision of the Android NDK given in android_ndk_repository rule 'androidndk' is '14.0.3770861'.
ERROR: /home/alexluk/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl:220:6: name 'WITH_GCP_SUPPORT' is not defined.
ERROR: /home/alexluk/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/android/BUILD:72:1: error loading package 'tensorflow/core': Extension 'tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl' has errors and referenced by '//tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so'.
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo' failed; build aborted.
```

Comment: Maybe it's related. When I run the following code:

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be building a broken version of the build system. If you cloned the TensorFlow repository between [13:04 PDT](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/bce77b91f958840a3c8a037993ccd8247fa61758) at [13:55 PDT](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/7624fbccae91e11d31f4b623473b6e64e30ec1b5) on 3/14/2017, the file `tensorflow/core/platform/default/build_config.bzl` was in a broken state. It has now been fixed, so you can pull the latest `master` branch, and should be able to build that version as normal.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate on how to pull the master branch? should i delete the tensorflow file and download it again?

Comment: Assuming you are in the root of the TensorFlow git repository, and you cloned it using `git clone ...`, the command `git pull origin master` should retrieve and checkout the latest code.